# border-radius adds space between elements (IE11)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-11

Whitespace appears around elements with `border-radius` larger than 0, but only on IE.

*With `border-top-left-radius: 20px;` `border-top-right-radius: 20px;`:*

[image]

*Without `border-radius`:

[image]

**The Code:**

```css
.price-head {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  height: 109px;
}
.btop {
  background: #8ebded;
}
.bbot {
  background-color: #4096ee;
  height: 80px;
  position:relative;
}
.bbot:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 63%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 20px #4096ee;
  border-left: solid 20px transparent;
  border-right: solid 20px transparent;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
  <div class="row text-center" style="margin: 0;">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="margin: 0;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
      <div class="col-md-3 price-head btop" style="border-top-left-radius: 20px;">
        <h1 style="padding-top: 15px;"><strong>Sole Trader</strong></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 price-head btop">
        <h1><strong>Small Business</strong></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 price-head btop">
        <h1 style="padding-top: 15px;"><strong>SME</strong></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 price-head btop" style="border-top-right-radius: 20px;">
        <h1 style="padding-top: 15px;"><strong>Contractor</strong></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center" style="margin: 0;">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="margin: 0;">
      <h3>Choose Plan</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
      <div class="col-md-3 price-head bbot">
        <h1>£</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 price-head bbot">
        <h1>££</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 price-head bbot">
        <h1>£££</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 price-head bbot">
        <h1>££££</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried changing the transparent borders for bbot:after to #4096ee?

Comment: bbot:after is with regards to the small blue triangle at the bottom of the header. Removing the transparency makes the triangle a square and has no effect on the elements with whitespace.

Comment: apologies, I had a blonde moment. From what I've read, the solution can be to add a border around the element, the problem in your case is that you have a gradient background.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
.col-md-3 { border-width:0 !important; }
```